# Количество перестановок в быстрой сортировке и сортировке выбором

Tags: сортировка, qsort

Реализовал алгоритмы сортировки выбором и быстрой сортировки.
Результат при сортировке 3000 элементов:

Выбором:

```
Сравнений: 4498500
Перестановок: 2975
```

Быстрая:

```
Сравнений: 80496
Перестановок: 18027
```

Это нормально что при быстрой сортировке больше перестановок или я неправильно реализовал алгоритм?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нормально.

Сортировка выбором вообще делает наименьшее количество перестановок (изо всех сортировок, основанных на сравнениях и обменах) - не более n (меньше на число элементов, уже стоящих на своих местах, если реализация это учитывает)